# CountDown is not rendering correctly on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, countdown

I have a chat app on React and when chat can not connect, reconnect modal (ant d) is opened

[image]

And I want that, when I click the ''reconnect``` button, the countdown must work. But it only works when I click, and after it stops.

I think React can not render because on the console it repeats.

[image]

Maybe it depends on `Websocket`.

My codes

```
  const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(60);
  const [reconnectModal, setReconnectModal] = useState(false);

  const reconnectFunction = () => {
    connect(); // connect is for Websocket. I can connect the chat with this function.
    setInterval(() => {
      setCountDown(countDown - 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

    <Modal
        visible={reconnectModal}
        okText={`Reconnect ${`(${countDown})`}`}
        cancelText="Close"
        onOk={reconnectFunction}
        onCancel={() => setReconnectModal(false)}
      >
        Connection failed. Please try again
    </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you set the interval it will convert the `countDown` with the actual value (default here is 60).
So when it update the value of `countDown`, it will not update this value in the interval.

I think you can simply change to :

```
setInterval(() => {
  setCountDown((v) => v - 1);
}, 1000);
```

As the `v` is always the last value of the state.

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-fast-9mwitz?file=/src/App.js).

Don't forget to handle when the count is at 0. And maybe have the interval in a ref to cancel it when you are connected and therefore no need to continue the interval.